# Watermark in scale

Tags: php

I have Watermark and I want to adapt to the images.

i'd like that the watermark was always at the top left and it was great 10% compared to the image

i try with this

```
$scale = min(
    $watermark_o_width / $imageSize[0], $watermark_o_height / $imageSize[1]
);

$newWatermarkWidth = $watermark_o_width * $scale;
$newWatermarkHeight = $watermark_o_height * $scale;
```

but the size is wrong !

Comment: What exactly goes wrong where? What do you mean by "wrong"?

Comment: You need to calculate 10% from your image size on at least one axis. The other one must remain dynamic, unless you can live with a distorted watermark (which nobody usually wants).

Comment: In little image watermark is very large, in large image very little

Comment: and than i'd like have "max" domension for my watermark

Comment: You'll need to provide more info. The size of the original image; the size of the watermark; the size that comes up; and the results of the calculations you make above.

Comment: the original image i don't know, it's variable...the watermark for now il 176*60 but it's for test

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the watermark ratio:

```
$watermark_ratio = $watermark_old_width / $watermark_old_height;
```

Make sure the watermark's width is 10% of the image width:

```
$watermark_new_width = $image_width * 0.1;
```

Compute the desired watermark height:

```
$watermark_new_height = $watermark_new_width / $watermark_ratio;
```

If you want to calculate for the other axis, just use

```
$watermark_new_height = $image_height * 0.1;
```

And then compute the desired width:

```
$watermark_new_width = $watermark_new_height * $watermark_ratio;
```

Comment: What library are you using to do the image processing? GD? ImageMagick?

Comment: GD use imagecopyresized and imagecopyresampled

Comment: Note the `quality` parameter in your GD method calls. Example: `imagejpeg($anything, NULL, 90);` and `90` is the quality represented as percentage. [Refer to the according GD documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to learn how to apply the `quality` parameter to the functions you are using.

Comment: in little image (for example 300x300) loose quality in "big" image like800*600 my Watermark is good

Comment: `$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images/watermark.png');
imagealphablending($watermark, true);
imagesavealpha($watermark, true);`

No change